# string.compare for c++

Tags: c++, io, compare

I am asking user to input a word then have my program compare it with an input .txt file
but even tho I type in exactly a word in data.txt it still executes false.

```
//------------in my data.txt---------
// Banana Bed Today
// Apples Chair Window
// Corn Tomorrow Hive

string testData;
  cout<<"enter Data: ";
  cin>>testData;
  for(i=0; i<s.size()-1; i++){
    if (testData.compare(s[i]->name) == 0)
      cout<<"Right\n";
    if (youkno.compare(s[i]->name) != 0)
        cout<<"Wrong\n";
  }
```

if i prompt Banana then output excuted wrong

Comment: How do you read the test data (`s`)? Your code also contains errors but this isn’t relevant for your particular example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you replace:

```
for(i=0; i<s.size()-1; i++){
```

with:

```
for(i=0; i<s.size(); i++){  // Adjusting to check last entry as well.
    cout << "[" << s[i]->name << "][" << testData << "]" << endl;
```

you may find it becomes blindingly obvious. There's a good chance that one of your strings is not quite what you expect.

Comment: thanks. I dont know why I didnt think of testing it that way.

Answer (score 1):

What is in `s[i]->name`?  If you read that data from a file, you may have included the line endings in the `name` variable.

Also, why not use `operator==` ?

EDIT: just noticed you have an off by one error.  your for loop should be

```
for(i=0; i<s.size(); i++)
```

Otherwise you don't compare the last value item in `s`

Comment: I think the major difference with `op==` is that a temp string object is created (not that it matters unless you're _really_ after performance).

Comment: @paxdiablo operator== does not create a temporary

Comment: Internet says otherwise at least in the case where one is a `char*` - `compare` doesn't seem to have that behaviour or at least it's not documented: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/operators/ (although I have no knowledge about the veracity of that site and I'd be more than willing to be proved wrong).

Comment: @paxdiablo we don't know what type `s[i]->name` is though.  If it's a std::string, then no temporary os created